# Moving code from external c# project library into Unity without broken references

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have received an old project that I need to maintain. The problem is that the main bulk of the code is inside an external c# project library that's compiled to a DLL which then is imported by Unity. It's not impossible to work with, but every time the external project is compiled and I go back into unity, it freezes for 20 secs before I can run any scene.

My question is if there is any way to move the code from this library straight into Unity without breaking script references in my scenes and prefabs?

Or is my only alternative to copy the files and manually find all broken references?

Comment: It kinda depents on how u setup your project. Unity does not rly have a project strucutre. When starting your Unity Project with VS you have 1 solution with all projects including yours and all the unity buildin ones. Therefore you cannot have a project in unity that easly. Dlls also are kinda a head to get on. I would recommend to coppy it all in an extra folder in your project if you really want to work with it that way or just go on with the dll as u do right now.

Comment: Yeah, I removed the DLL and copied to the code into Unity and ran a script to find all broken references. Finally I manually compared the broken references with an old revision of the code to find the correct script and fix it. Took some work, but some hours later it seems to be working, worth it!

Comment: Happy to hear this. Have fun coding :D